# What do I do about bright spots in my Nikon D810 images?

Tags: nikon, spots

My putative albeit non-existent Nikon D810 sometimes has bright spots in the image on long exposures when in 1.2X crop mode.

Is this a known problem?
Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you post an example photo of these "bright spots"?

Answer (score 4):

> What do I do about bright spots in my Nikon D810 images?

[**DPReview advise that**](http://www.dpreview.com/articles/3182497502/nikon-announces-service-advisory-for-d810-bright-spots)    <- Click me

- Nikon has announced a service advisory (in mid August 2014) for the Nikon D810, in response to reports of 'bright spots' at long shutter speeds and in 1.2X crop mode. According to an announcement on Nikon's website, affected cameras will be serviced free of charge.

  Apparently, the issue only affects cameras within a certain serial number range, and if you're lucky enough to have got hold of a D810 already, you can check the serial number of your camera against Nikon's database via the company's service and support pages.

Affected cameras will be, no surprise, repaired for free.
Sounds like Sony got something wrong :-(.

[Nikon USA advisory page here](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Service-And-Support/Service-Advisories/hyvanded/Technical-Service-Advisory-for-Users-of-the-Nikon-D810.html)

[Nikon US serial number checking page](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/D810/sn)

[Nikon Europe advisory page here](https://nikoneurope-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/61871)

[Nikon Europe serial number checking page](http://advisory.nikonrepair.eu/language_select_D810.aspx)

Unlike the USAian page you are given the choice of using any of 24 languages.

If your D810 is in the relevant serial number range and/but has a black spot as shown in the photo below then it has already been checked and/or fixed.

[image]